# How to insert data to sql database using nodejs and sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am creating a REST API  using nodejs , express , MySql server , sequelize

I want to save the following object to my database.

```
let dataToSave = {

    "config": {
        "id": "1697141843496"
        "user_id": 27856,
        "imageurl": "my url",
        "name": "Ikea",
        "server": "Google",
        "size": "300x600",
        "imageWidth": "300",
        "imageHeight": "600",
        "hide_logo": 0,
        "point_color": "#1c846a",
        "pulse": true,
    },
    "points": [
        {
            "pointId": "292155",
            "x": 60.06711409395973,
            "y": 22.909698996655518,
            "tooltip": {
                "toltipId": "292155",
                "title": "Window",
                "price": "400",
                "link": "https://interactive-img.com/editimage?image_id=52711",
                "tooltipThumbnailUrl": "blob:http://localhost:4200/c5a7369a-94bc-423d-b3f3-474a30aad69f",
                "right": "",
                "left": "40%",
                "top": "18%"
            }
        },
        {
            "pointId": "216572",
            "x": 63.758389261744966,
            "y": 70.40133779264214,
            "tooltip": {
                "toltipId": "216572",
                "title": "Jiko",
                "price": "9000",
                "link": "https://interactive-img.com/editimage?image_id=52711",
                "tooltipThumbnailUrl": "blob:http://localhost:4200/6b26099d-75c2-4f1c-ba06-dd9e0cca14d4",
                "right": "",
                "left": "43.6667%",
                "top": "65.3333%"
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

How can I create model based on the above object ?

This is what I have tried so far.

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = model;
function model(sequelize) {
    const attributes = {
        config: {
            type: DataTypes.JSON, 
        },
        points: {
            type: DataTypes.JSON, 
        },
    };

    const options = {
        defaultScope: {
            attributes: { exclude: ['hash'] }
        },
        scopes: {
            withHash: { attributes: {} }
        }
    };

    return sequelize.define('data', attributes, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create the `Model` based on the data provided by you, I would be breaking down them down into three sub-models, one for `config`, another one for `point` and the last one for `tooltip` since those are the three feature of interest which we're looking at. So in you `models` directory

```js
// ./models/configModel.js

const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const Config = sequelize.define('Config', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        imageurl: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        server: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        size: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        imageWidth: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        imageHeight: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        hide_logo: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        point_color: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        pulse: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
        }
    });

    return Config;
};
```

```js
// ./models/pointModel.js

const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const Point = sequelize.define('Point', {
        pointId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        x: {
            type: DataTypes.FLOAT
        },
        y: {
            type: DataTypes.FLOAT
        }
    });

    return Point;
};
```

```js
// ./models/tooltipModel.js

const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const Tooltip = sequelize.define('Tooltip', {
        tooltipId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        price: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        link: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        tooltipThumbnailUrl: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        right: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        left: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        top: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    });

    return Tooltip;
};
```

Once the three models have been created; then I would define a `/saveData` route inside my `app.js` or `server.js` file(this is opinionated and for simplicity I used, you can follow the routes folder approach as well) where the `POST` request happens.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('./config'); // Your database config
const Config = require('./models/configModel');
const Point = require('./models/pointModel');
const Tooltip = require('./models/tooltipModel');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Rest of your code including your db sync code...

app.post('/saveData', async (req, res) => {
    const dataToSave = req.body;

    // Save config data
    const config = await Config.create(dataToSave.config);

    // Save points data
    for(let point of dataToSave.points) {
        const tooltip = await Tooltip.create(point.tooltip);
        point.tooltip = tooltip.id;
        const savedPoint = await Point.create(point);
    }

    res.send({ message: 'Data fetch Success' });
});

// Some other code

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

This code will start the server on port `3000`. You can then send a `POST` request from you app or via some **[client](https://www.postman.com/)** to `http://localhost:3000/saveData` with your data object in the body to save the data to the database. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please following below code :
**db.data** is your model define

```
var dataToSave = {
  config : your_json,
  points : your_json
}
await db.data.create(dataToSave)
 .then(async (data) => { return true; })
 .catch(async (err) => { console.log(err.message.toString())});
```